# Canceling United Flight - Credit Policy

Tags: cancellations, united-airlines

I need to cancel or possibly change an international flight on United with a non-refundable ticket (class T). When I log in to the app and hit cancel, the credit shown is the exact amount I paid for the ticket - $953. Within the credit box, it says "change fees may apply," but doesn't show any sort of deduction. I've read online they can charge up to $400 in change fees.

I'm scared to hit the confirmation button. Will I get back a full credit of $953? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that one of United's current [waivers](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/notices.html) to the change fee applies to your trip?

Comment: @zach-lipton Not as of yet. One of the flights is through Rome, but United hasn't included FCO on their airport list yet.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that they will "credit" you $953, but the fee will be charged when you go to use that credit to pay for another flight.

Comment: How... misleading... of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

United Airlines uses a "New Money" concept for change fees.

Basically this means that you can cancel your flight at this time and receive a $953 credit voucher.  However in order to use that voucher at a later stage you will need to pay $400 "new money" (ie, the $400 can't come out of the voucher value), and then you'll be able to use the full $953 value of the credit.

Depending on when the trip is, you may want to wait until it's a little closer to the date to see if they add Rome to their [waiver list](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/notices.html) for areas affected by the Coronavirus. If they do that you will likely be able to (at least) avoid paying the change fee.  The refund amount/change fee won't change over time, so as long as you cancel at least a day or two before the flight there's no reason not to wait.

Comment: Given that the CDC [recommends](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/warning/coronavirus-italy), as of a few hours ago, avoiding non-essential travel to all of Italy, I suspect that waiver list may be expanding soon.